dotnet datagridview adding image to column shows incorrectly
I have a c# Winforms app with a datagridview that has five columns.  The second column is defined in Visual Studio as a DataGridViewImageColumn.  In a test application, the attached code works fine. When I integrated the code into a large complex program,the datagrid display shows nothing in the 2-5 cols. I have verified by looking into the datagrid row values under debug mode that all the information is in the datagrid cells properly so this really is just a display issue.

If I remove the bitmap from the object by setting it to null, everything displays correctly in all columns except the image column.  I suspect some kind of memory problem but don't know how to track that down.
Any thoughts and suggestions on how to fix or track down whats wrong?
original = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(outfiletn + ".jpg");
                            
Filedatagrid.Rows.Add(new object[] {
   file.Substring(directory_name.Length + 1),
   original,
   filetypes[i].Substring(2),
   sizeInKb,
   File.GetCreationTime(file)
});
                            
original.Dispose();


Why do you original.Dispose(); if you want to display it? Remove that.

Consider the following which iterates a folder using globbing.
The following iterates a folder were the patterns array specifies which files to include while the excludePattern array are for files to exclude.
public static async Task GetImages(string parentFolder, string[] patterns, string[] excludePatterns)
{

    Matcher matcher = new();
    matcher.AddIncludePatterns(patterns);
    matcher.AddExcludePatterns(excludePatterns);
    
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {

        foreach (string file in matcher.GetResultsInFullPath(parentFolder))
        {
            TraverseFileMatch?.Invoke(new FileMatchItem(file));
        }
    });

    Done?.Invoke("Finished");

}

The model which is used to populate a list where the list becomes the DataSource for the DataGridView (in the sample there are no columns defined).
public class FileItem
{
    [Browsable(false)]
    public string Folder { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    [Browsable(false)]
    public byte[] Bytes { get; set; }
    public Image Image => Bytes.BytesToImage();
    public long Size { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => Path.Combine(Folder, FileName);
}

Extension method to create an Image.
public static class Extensions
{
    public static Image BytesToImage(this byte[] bytes)
    {
        var imageData = bytes;
        using MemoryStream ms = new(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
        ms.Write(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
        return Image.FromStream(ms, true);
    }
}

Form code
You need to change folder and glob patterns or adjust the code to not use the arrays.
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private static List<FileItem> _files = [];
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Shown += MainForm_Shown;
    }

    private async void MainForm_Shown(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] include = ["**/Ri*.png", "**/Bl*.png"];
        string[] exclude = ["**/blog*.png", "**/black*.png"];
        var folder = "C:\\Users\\paynek\\Documents\\Snagit";

        if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
            return;
        
        GlobbingOperations.TraverseFileMatch += DirectoryHelpers_TraverseFileMatch;
        GlobbingOperations.Done += DirectoryHelpers_Done;
        await GlobbingOperations.GetImages(folder, include,exclude);
        
        dataGridView1.DataSource = _files;
        dataGridView1.FixHeaders();
        dataGridView1.ExpandColumns();
    }

    private void DirectoryHelpers_TraverseFileMatch(FileMatchItem sender)
    {
        var item = new FileItem() { Folder = sender.Folder, FileName = sender.FileName };
        item.Bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(item.Folder,item.FileName));
        var info = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(item.Folder, item.FileName));
        item.Size = info.Length;
        item.CreationTime = info.CreationTime;
        _files.Add(item);
    }
    private void DirectoryHelpers_Done(string message)
    {
        _files = _files.OrderBy(x => x.FileName).ToList();
    }
}


See DEV article C# file/folder helpers which also has a GitHub repository.

Thanks for looking.  I will look into globbing.  For brevity, the snippet shown is just a part. The program inputs file (pdf, tiff, jpeg, etc) extracting the images from those files, ocring the image to create an abstract, resizing the image into a thumbnail, parsing the pdf into pieces, and then putting the created image into the datagrid so I can see correct conversion.  The other information in the datagrid is there for information purposes.  I still don't understand why the code snippet works in a standalone program and not in the larger integrated program.

Please check the extension method BytesToImage. You must keep the stream open.
